# How to close the Html window after the form submitted automatically

Tags: javascript, html

We have two html pages. First Page we are opening the second page using `window.open("./pop.html", "",'width=200,height=100');`

In the `pop.html` we are submitting the form automatically and we need to close the HTML after submission. The code is given below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadForm() {
    var  method = "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.
    var path = "http://localhost:8080";
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "username");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "sai");

    var passField = document.createElement("input");
    passField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    passField.setAttribute("name", "password");
    passField.setAttribute("value", "sai123");

    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    form.appendChild(passField);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();

    window.close(); 
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadForm();">
<form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But `window.close();` not working in page. Is it missing anything?

Comment: I think due to security issues this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Open and close a window by the window name. Example:

Open window:

```
var my_window = window.open("URL_HERE", "my_window", "height=100,width=100");
```

Close window:

```
my_window.close();
```

Or inside the content of my_window:

```
window.close();
```

Comment: Here we have two pages.  In the page1 we are opening  var my_window = window.open("URL_HERE", "my_window", "height=100,width=100"); and we need to close the second page automatically after login success.

Comment: Okay so in the popup use window.close() to close the window like I mentoined in my example.

Answer (score 0):

The [window close() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp) should do what you want.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">close</a>

<script>
function close_window(){
    close();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it setting an interval in first window that close second window

```
var secondWindow;
function openWindow(){
    secondWindow=window.open("./pop.html", "",'width=200,height=100');
    setTimeout(function(){
        secondWindow.close();
    },500);
}
```

You have to find exact time for timeout